# Escape 0x1b;t;0x7 command code For printer

Tags: python, vb6, escaping, codepages, chr

How I can translate following working VisualBasic code to Python?

`print #1,Chr$(&H1B) & "t"  & Chr$(7)`(running on Windows)

I tried this (for Ubuntu):

```
    kkm_port = open(stg.kkm_port,"a")
    print >> kkm_port,chr(0x1B)
    print >> kkm_port,"t"
    print >> kkm_port,chr(7)
```

This code must switch termal printer CITIZEN CT-S310 codepage. Whats wrong?

Comment: I don't know anything about Python, but it looks as if you're outputting a <newline> after every character, while the VB code only outputs one after the set of three characters.

Comment: You are right. Thank you very match!